# Is it possible to draw paths or import LineString placemarks from a KML file and display in Qlik Sense maps?

Tags: kml, qliksense

I've several KML files with several paths as LineString placemarks which I would like to plot in Qlik Sense maps. I've tried to load the KML file directly, but Qlik Sense doesn't recognize any LineString placemark (only points and polygons).

Is there any some way to display those paths on Qlik Sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a video guide on using maps in Qlik Sense that specifically refers to KML files [here](https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-6941)